# Unable to remove lockfile

Tags: python, lockfile

I'm trying to use [zc.lockfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.lockfile).  I see that a lockfile is created in the same directory as my python script, but when I press ctrl+C, the file is NOT removed.  I have a callback registered and have even tested given a long time (not sure if zc.lockfile spawns a new thread and needed time to complete).

```
import os
import sys
import signal
import time
import zc.lockfile

program_lock = None

def onExitCodePressed(signal, frame):
  """Callback run on a premature user exit."""
  global program_lock
  print '\r\nYou pressed Ctrl+C'
  program_lock.close()
  time.sleep(5)
  sys.exit(0)

def main():
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, onExitCodePressed)

  if os.path.exists('myapp_lock'):
    print "\nAnother instance of the program is already running.\n"
    sys.exit(0)
  else:
    program_lock = zc.lockfile.LockFile('myapp_lock')

  while True:
    continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Dumb question, but are you actually calling main()? Because if this is your exact code, nothing will run.

Comment: yes i am, i was just trying to keep the code simple, editing now...

Comment: I really think this really overkill for just creating a file and then checking for it's existence.  That library doesn't seem to work (I can't ever properly close or remove the file).